# Rails: HABTM Relationship with id as Primary Key, legacy DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, primary-key, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a legacy DB with join tables that have IDs as primary keys... Is there anything I can do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of has_and_belongs_to_many, use

```
has_many :whatevers, :through => :habtm_table
```